# What are the special abilities of each class?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, I have noticed that some classes have special abilities. For example:

- Scouts can double jump
- Spys can cloak
- Pyros can air puff.

Now I know this is a pretty basic question, but **what are all the special abilities of each class?**

I know there may be multiple abilites for some classes, so could you please list them all.

Comment: Soldiers can rocket jump?

Comment: @aytimothy Not a special ability. Anybody can rocket jump in the specific circumstance where an enemy soldier fires a rocket at their feet, and the crouch and jump with the correct timing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sometimes difficult to define what would count as special abilities, rather than weapon traits, but I'll give it a go.

Scout:

- Double jump
- Highest move speed
- Fast but weak melee attack
- Low Health

Soldier:

- Rocket jumping
- Slow speed
- High health

Pyro:

- Immune to afterburn
- Most flamethrowers can airblast enemies/projectiles
- Many weapons set enemies on fire and/or are effective against burning enemies

Demoman:

- Sticky jumping (and, less common, grenade jumping)
- Can leave stickybombs and detonate them later
- Massive burst damage potential
- Slow reload
- Can swap out one or both of his ranged weapons to become stronger at melee - known as a demoknight

Heavy:

- Highest health of any class
- Slowest speed
- Miniguns require spinning up, making Heavy even slower

Engineer:

- Can build a sentry, which fires on enemies**
- Can build a dispenser, which heals and resupplies allies**
- Can build teleporters, which instantly send teammates** from on loaction to another
- Can repair and upgrade any building, even ones built by other teammates
- Low health

Medic:

- Can heal allies**
- Builds ubercharge by healing
- Natural health regeneration
- Slightly faster than most classes

Sniper:

- Sniper rifles have no damage falloff
- Sniper rifles do not randomly crit and always crit on headshots
- Sniper rifles charge while zoomed in and deal more damage the longer they are zoomed in.
- A fully charged headshot deals 450 damage and will one-shot almost anything
- Low health

Spy:

- Can disguise as enemies or teammates
- Can use cloak to become invisible
- Attacks from behind with a knife will always one-hit kill
- Low health

** Teammates and allies can also mean disguised spies on the enemy team

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Scout: Double Jump
Soldier: Rocket Jump
Pyro: Airblast
Demoman: Charge/Sticky jump
Heavy: Sandvich dropping/minigun spinning
Engineer: Building
Medic: Ubercharge
Sniper: Scope/zoom/head criticals
Spy: Disguise/Cloak/Instant backstab kills

These are the main ones.